# Setting HOSTNAME on startup

Tags: boot, hostname

Our lab group just purchased a dozen or so new workstations. They're Dells, so perhaps conveniently they report their service tag with `dmidecode -s system-serial-number`. We're thinking of using Clonezilla to easily deploy images across them all, but they each need to be set with a specific hostname and static IP address. So, combining the two seems straightforward using a lookup something like:

```
declare -A tags
tags=(["HKX321K"]="ws1name 10.32.54.10"
      ["HBZ321G"]="ws2name 10.32.54.11"
)
tag=$(sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number)
read -a nameip <<< "${tags[$tag]}"
wsname=${nameip[0]}
wsip=${nameip[1]}
```

`sed` or the like could then make a `/etc/hosts`, `hostname`, and `network/interfaces` files from some templates.  However, is modifying those files sufficient, and how do I execute the "personalization" script very early in boot before Ubuntu starts setting stuff up?

Is my plan bad for another unforeseen reason; what hidden pitfalls might await?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changing those files is sufficient. You can use the `hostnamectl` command to change the hostname easily. These changes need to be made only once. So you can make the changes via `rc.local` or something similar to run once, remove itself from whatever caused it to run at boot and then reboot one before going on to do other things.

If a reboot is too much extra work, you can try scheduling an Upstart job. An Upstart job which has a `start on startup` condition will run this as early as possible. Better yet, a job with `start on local-filesystems` will run early enough to be sure necessary filesystems are mounted.

Comment: Are you saying that I would need to let it boot all the way to login prompt (I don't know when `rc.local` runs exactly), let that config script run (which could self-destruct or otherwise inactivate itself) then reboot for changes to take effect?  Is there a way to do it in one go?

Comment: @NickT you don't need to do that, it's just the simplest way, and pretty much automated, so all it really does is add a couple of minutes to your installation time. You can create an upstart job which has a `start on startup` condition to achieve this as early as possible or better `start on local-filesystems` early enough to be sure necessary filesystems are mounted .